# Use SharePoint Search Query Web Part to find Read Only site collections

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

We have a special situation at our office where we "close" off a site collection when a project is complete.  Our architecture is setup such that each project in play is it's own site collection.  When the project is complete we close the project in SP by setting the site collection to read-only.

Part of our business would like to still view the closed site collections, but doesn't want to go through a list of them (I mean excel spreadsheet or some other external form of tracking), but instead wants to do it from a page in SP.  Our solution is to modify one of our other solutions (search query web part that finds all site collections they belong to) and only search on closed site collections.

I know how to determine if a site is ReadOnly or not in Powershell (#spSite.IsReadOnly), but that isn't going to work here and going through the properties in search I couldn't find anything that jumped out at me to do this.  Does anyone know how to return ReadOnly site collections in a Search Query Web Part?

Thank you.

Comment: You should move this question to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This also exists in that forum. I tried to get as many different views as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know of a managed property called: SiteClosed but I haven't got the slightest idea what it does. Looking at the name this might be the one to start with.
If this doesn't work I'm afraid the only other option is to create a custom Web Part...